# How to pass the parameters like username and password in windows phone 8 using http

Tags: windows-phone-8

Any one knew how to pass the parameters to post method using  HTTPWebrequest like web client as shown below.Please help me......

```
WebClient sharegroupclient = new WebClient();
Uri uristring = null;
uristring = new Uri(uri);
sharegroupclient.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
sharegroupclient.Credentials = _groupaccount.GetCredentials();

string JsonStringParams = "group_admin=" + _groupaccount.Username + "&search=" + searchtext.Text + "&action=" + "search_group";
sharegroupclient.UploadStringCompleted += wc_RemoveUserGroupStringCompleted;
sharegroupclient.UploadStringAsync(uristring, "POST", JsonStringParams);
```

Answer (score 1):

but why would you like to use `WebClient` when you can use `HttpClient`. To use `HttpClient` you just need to add [`this lib`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) from Microsoft itself.

**Code for `HttpClient`**

```
        HttpClient objClient = new HttpClient();
        MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
        form.Add(new StringContent("password text"), "Password key");
        form.Add(new StringContent("userID text"), "userID key");

        var response = await objClient.PostAsync(new Uri("URI string", UriKind.Absolute), form);
```

Hope that helps..!!